# How do I re-apply all of a branch's commits on top of master branch, but keep it in it's own branch?

Tags: git, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

Okay, that may be hard to understand from the title. Basically I have a Wordpress plugin, and I'd like to use the same repository for both the full version and the lite version of the plugin. I got this great idea from [a great post about this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2540471/1809762) elsewhere on Stackoverflow.

The idea is that you have a branch for the lite version, which has deleted files/code. Every time you update the master branch, you "rebase" the lite branch, which then basically takes all the changes in the master branch and inserts them under the lite branch--like the lite branch is re-applying all the deletions on top of it again.

Conceptually, I at least vaguely understand it...but I don't know how to carry it out. Here are some illustrations. Let's say I have two branches:

[image]

I'd like to take all the latest changes in master and insert them "under" the lite branch, like this (though I have a hunch  my diagram incorrectly depicts how it actually takes place).

[image]

I'd love it if someone could:

1. Tell me how to carry out the task
2. Correct me where I'm misunderstanding it conceptually, if I am

Also, I've used git via CLI in the past, but am now using Sourcetree. I am fine with any CLI answers, but if you happen to have Sourcetree-specific answers, those are welcome too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, your diagram looks fine, and from the CLI you would just do:

```
$ git checkout lite
$ git rebase
```

assuming you have told git to set `master` as the "upstream" for `lite`.

If you have not done this upstream setting, you can either do it, or use one extra word for the `rebase` command, to specify the upstream:

```
$ git rebase master
```

What rebase does is:

- find the current branch's upstream, or use the one you told it to use (whichever is appropriate)
- find the merge-base between HEAD and the upstream
- copy each commit that is on the current branch but not on the upstream—these are the two purple commits in your first diagram—with each copy being done by:

  - diff the commit against its parent
  - apply those changes to a new (anonymous, detached-HEAD) branch being grown from the tip of the upstream
  - commit the just-applied changes
- once all commits are copied, snip the branch label off the original branch and make it point to the new tip-most copied commit.

That's really the whole thing, if we ignore a few corner and special cases.  Specifically, git will detect if a change made in the branch being rebased (a diff hunk) is also already in the upstream, and omit changes or even entire commits as appropriate; sometimes git won't be able to apply a diff and will stop and need help (just like `git merge`); and in very rare cases, git will go to apply a diff, and will put it in the wrong place, producing a bad "copy" (also just like `git merge`—in fact, rebase can do a full 3-way merge for each commit it copies, if necessary).

As with merge, you should inspect the results, in case git got the "re-apply previous change" thing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, what you're describing is the standard rebase workflow.  To rebase your `lite` branch on the `master` branch:

1. Update the master branch, if it's not already up-to-date:

   ```
   git checkout master
   git pull
   ```
2. Switch back to your `lite` branch:

   ```
   git checkout lite
   ```
3. Rebase on the master branch:

   ```
   git rebase master
   ```

And now you have exactly what you've described with your second picture.  It is possible at this point that you will need to resolve some merge conflicts, if you have made changes that conflict with changes that were made on the master branch.  GitHub has some good information on how to resolve merge conflicts [here](https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-merge-conflicts-after-a-git-rebase/).